# How do I move the edge weights to Vertex weights in Igraph Python

Tags: python, nodes, igraph, vertex

I have an `igraph.Graph` object with edges having weights. For each vertex I want to sum up the weights of the adjacent edges and assign it to a new vertex attribute `gg.vs['weight']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `strength()` method of `Graph` objects - it should do exactly what you need (i.e. calculate the sum of some edge attribute for the incident edges of a given vertex and then assign it to a vertex).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the indices of the edges a given vertex is incident on with the `adjacent` method of the `igraph.Graph` instance. From here it is straightforward to sum the weights of those edges:

```
import igraph

g = igraph.Graph.Barabasi(n = 10, m = 3)
g.es['weight'] = range(g.ecount())
g.vs['weight'] = [sum(g.es[eid]['weight']
                      for eid in g.adjacent(v.index, mode = 'ALL'))
                  for v in g.vs]
```